# Automated Timetable in Genetic Algorithm using PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, yii, genetic-algorithm

I wanna ask if it is possible to create an automated timetable system which use Genetic Algorithm using PHP?

I'm thinking about using YiiFramework but I fear that I cannot use GA in implementing the system.

The reason why I use PHP is because I'm more comfortable in PHP. I've done it in JAVA but didn't comfortable with JAVA. And now I'm thinking about shifting it to PHP.

Please help me.
Thanx in advance.!

Comment: amit.thanks for replying. i just wanna know if it is possible to create the system I mentioned using PHP.If it is possible. Then I think to shift to PHP. I'm pretty ok with PHP so I think I can catch the due date more fast.. I use JAVA before but didn't achieve much(design issue,code issue.database issue).

Comment: I am not familiar with php, but if I am not mistaken, it is [turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), so yes, you can. However - java is built much better for doing such things, and you are more likely to use built in libraries that implement most things for you.

Comment: In theory, anything you can do with java, you should be able to do with php. What do you mean exactly by an automated timetable system? What does the system actually do?

Comment: amit.. thankks! basically i'm not comfortable with java. even with the built in.

Comment: deacs.. thanx for replying.. well actually it is for university course timetabling problem.

It will use genetic algorithm to assign the timeslot and room for each course/group for learning to take part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. I gather from your question, that you are going to code the algorithm by yourself, so, of course you can use PHP and yii instead of java.

Another thing I can see, is that you opt to use web to enable teachers and other actors to submit their favorites to your database so that you can gather your soft constraints. This is where Yiiframework comes very very handy and easy.

Side note: why don't you consider a combination of local search algorithms (e.g. tabu search) and constraint programming. I can talk more about this approach if you like.

Comment: Thanx aladdin for your answer.. It really helps me..and now I feel much more confidence to code it in PHP!

Well.. technically I only have 1-2 months left.. So I don't quite think I should get everything messed up by adding more technique.. (Actually I just downgrade my technique from Guided Search GA to GA only approach due to limited resource..) 

Btw.. Thanx Aladdin!

Comment: wish you all the best

Answer (score 1):

Although technically it is possible as Aladdin has answered, I would strongly suggest you not to use PHP/Yii for this. Neither Yii nor PHP is desgined for this sort of work. Yii is really a wonderful framework but it won't really help you with GA programming. PHP is versatile and fast, great for scripting etc. But it is not designed to be used in cases of GA where you will run many generations and runtime performance is a big factor. C++ or similar performing languages you should be considering.

You mentioned time as a constraint both run time  and development time. I would advice you to use a existing python/C++ library for GA algorithims and quickly implement the same

Python Library: http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/ Source here: https://github.com/perone/Pyevolve

C++ Library: http://lancet.mit.edu/ga/

If performance of the algorithm is extremely important then C++ is the obvious choice. If presentation and flexibility then use the Python one, which I prefer personally.

However if you wish to still use Yii/PHP, i suggest you compile these programs and call them in a console application / command in Yii and just use Yii to process the parameters store and display the output.

Comment: thanks for sharing the link libraries, I will use the one for python.